# How to validate empty field in angularjs with custom message based on table row

Tags: angularjs

I have a table,in which data is coming from some json. Here I need the validation for input field based on particular row.User can able to submit the form if he/she can fill at least one text box of the particular row.For ex. if any one field of first row contains some text, user can able to submit.but if all textbox of first row is empty user can't submit.similarly for second/third row.Below is my code.Thanks in advance.

### HTML

```
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css'>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container" ng-app="problemApp" data-ng-controller="validationCtrl">
  <form name="form1">
  <table>
  <tr ng-repeat="item in testdata">
  <td>
    <input type="text"  required value={{item.name}}>
    </td>
    <td>
    <input required type="text" >
    </td>
    <td>
    <input required type="text" >
    </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <button type="submit">submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
  <script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.5/angular.min.js'></script>
<script  src="js/index.js"></script>
```

### index.js

```
var app=angular.module('problemApp', []);
app.controller('validationCtrl',function($scope,$http){

var request = {
                method: 'get',
                url: 'test.json',
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: "application/json"
            };
            $scope.testdata = new Array;
            $http(request)
                .success(function (json) {
                    $scope.testdata = json;
                    $scope.list = $scope.testdata;
                })
                .error(function () {

                });

$scope.dataTableOpt = {
   //custom datatable options 
  // or load data through ajax call also
  "aLengthMenu": [[10, 50, 100,-1], [10, 50, 100,'All']],
  };
});
```

### test.json

```
[{
        "countryId": 1,
        "name": "France - Mainland",
        "desc": "some description"
    },
    {
        "countryId": 2,
        "name": "Gibraltar",
        "desc": "some description"
    },
    {
        "countryId": 3,
        "name": "Malta",
        "desc": "some description"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

- You should checkout AngularJs's `ng-submit` directive for form submission. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit
- All the logic related to your requirement will be in this function which you call on `ng-submit`. Possibly like this:

  `let showError = flase;
   $scope.formSubmit = function(){
     $scope.testdata.map((item)=>{
      if(item == ''){
       showError = true; // Using this variable, you show the error in your view.
    }
  });
  }`

  This `formSubmit` function will be used in you HTML as: `<form name="form1" ng-submit="formSubmit()">`
- And lastly, you should remove HTML `required` attributes multiple times as you are allowing any one to be filled (and not all).

Hope it helps you.